# discord.py FFmpegPCMAudio stops playing sound in the middle of sound file

Tags: python, audio, discord

I am trying to build a discord bot in python, that selects random wikipedia page, than converts it into sound file using gTTS and play it in discord voice channel.
My code looks like that:

```
file = "file.mp3"
# initialize tts, create mp3 and play
tts = gTTS(txt, 'cz', lang="cs")
tts.save(file)
vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="/usr/bin/ffmpeg", source=file, **ffmpeg_options))
# Sleep while audio is playing.
while vc.is_playing():
     sleep(.1)
```

When I run that code, it works for about maybe 30 seconds, and than audio stops playing. When I try to stop the code using Ctrl + C, it doesn't work...

I've searched a lot, but it seems like nobody can answer this question.

Please help

Comment: did you check what you have in `file.mp3` ? Maybe `gTTS` created only 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answere it's because your bot runs on an eventloop which is asynchronous. So normally the bot would process some bytes of the audio add it to buffer and then get into your loop. But to play the whole audio the eventloop has to process next bytes of the audio again. Now your loop stucks the eventloop from going there as sleep is a synchronous function and you only listen what is primarily in the buffer. So try first importing asyncio then insted of sleep do await asyncio.sleep(). It would let the eventloop go do other work till the time period is complete.

```py
import asyncio
file = "file.mp3"
# initialize tts, create mp3 and play
tts = gTTS(txt, 'cz', lang="cs")
tts.save(file)
vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="/usr/bin/ffmpeg", source=file, **ffmpeg_options))
# Sleep while audio is playing.
while vc.is_playing():
     await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

It will solve your problem